# Corda Flow library -CashIssueFlow error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/corda/finance/flows/CashIssueFlow

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, corda

I use **Flow** in the **Corda Flow library**, which is fine in the compiler. When I run this Flow in the shell, I get an error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/corda/finance/flows/CashIssueFlow

How can I solve it? thank you very much

```
OpaqueBytes issueRef=OpaqueBytes.of(new byte[1]);
        CashIssueFlow.IssueRequest issueRequest = new 
CashIssueFlow.IssueRequest(businessContractAmount, issueRef, notary);
            subFlow(new CashIssueFlow(issueRequest));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the Finance CorDapp on your node by placing it in your node's `cordapps` directory at start-up.

If you're using `deployNodes` to create your nodes, you can have it included automatically using:

```
node {
    ...
    cordapps = ["$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
    ...
}
```